# SQL Server 2016 Execute Permission Denied

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am running SQL Server 2016 and have setup role based access to control what users can do based on roles.

I've setup a role:

```
Create Role [Developer]
```

I've granted permissions on that role to run SELECTS, buy deny INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE on all tables:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::dbo to [Developer]
DENY INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::dbo to [Developer]
```

I add users to the role:

```
ALTER ROLE [Developer] ADD MEMBER [SomeUser]
```

I want the user to execute only specific stored procedures, so I grant execute permissions on the specific sprocs to the role:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.mySproc to [Developer]
```

However, when I login as SomeUser and try to execute the sproc, I am getting the following error:

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'mySproc', database 'MyDB', schema 'dbo'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: did you map a login to the database user? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/96358/how-can-i-map-a-login-to-a-database-using-t-sql-not-ssms

Comment: I did map a login using the following:  

CREATE USER [myDomain\SomeUser] FOR LOGIN [myDomain\SomeUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA [dbo].

This did not fix the problem.

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing all users from the role and deleting the role and recreating the role and adding back the users from the role.  I think I might have added a DENY EXECUTE on the dbo schema the first time around.  However I did not see this denial when viewing the role permissions.

Comment: you have to "select objects of type" -> "database", to see the permissions set at the database level. it doesn't automatically show up in the search results like object level permissions.

Comment: I see that now.  Thank you.